# compiled pdf doesn't show utf-8 character

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode

If i compile a document with lualatex that contains specific utf-8 characters most pdf-viewers (okular, evince, xpdf) don't show them. For example if i compile the following example i just see a bank page.

My tex/latex distribution is texlive 2014 and runs on a debian (jessie) system.

Maybe someone around here have a solution how to make those glyphs visible?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine Display O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}
%
% specific unicode characters
%
✧ ⎘ ✲
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a font that has the symbols. E.g. `\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}`.

Comment: Set `\tracinglostchars=2`, then TeX reports, if characters are missing in the font.

Comment: The NEXT PAGE symbol U+2398 is not in my copy of Arial Unicode MS; it is in Code2000, FreeSerif and FreeMono.

Comment: This comment is perhaps a bit off-topic, but... What are 6-byte utf-8 chars? According to what I know about UTF-8, the longest possible sequence is 4 bytes. Indeed, the characters you pasted (✧ ⎘ ✲) require only 3 bytes each (`e2` `9c` `a7`; `e2` `8e` `98` and `e2` `9c` `b2`, respectively)

Comment: @egreg & Ulrike: Thank you both, you get me on the right track. I have to blame gnome's font-manager application for the problem. The character maps of all fonts show these special symbols in this app. I'll inform the author about that... Best regards

Comment: @JLDiaz: You are right! It's my false that i naively counted the digits of the hex value. Of course it's a 6 nibble sequence and as the suggested solutions point out my problem has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @egreg: If you transform your comment into an answer i'll mark my question as answered! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a font that has the required glyphs. They are in FreeSerif, for instance. Here's how you can use them directly, by hiding the font change in a macro:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\newfontface{\freeserif}{FreeSerif} % for the required symbols
\newunicodechar{✧}{{\freeserif ✧}}
\newunicodechar{⎘}{{\freeserif ⎘}}
\newunicodechar{✲}{{\freeserif ✲}}

\begin{document}
✧ ⎘ ✲
\end{document}
```

[image]